# Not allowing space in input field React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation

I have got a register form which sends request with the first and last name and works fine. But, when a user enters `whitespace` it considers it as a valid input. The validation errors are sent from the api's response where a blank input gives an error. I tried to trim the firstname in `submit()` thinking that it it has spaces, it will remove it and consider as a blank input. But this doesnt seem to work. How can I implement the logic for it to trim the whitespace and not allow it.

```
export default class Signup extends Form {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {                
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',        
        };
    
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    }

    
    submit() {          
        let firstName=this.state.firstName.trim(); 
       
        return this.app.register({
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: this.state.lastName,
        }).then(account => success())
        .catch(e => {
            this.setState({ error: `signup_form_error_${e}` });
          })    
    }
    
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        })
    }

    render(props, state) {


        return <form onSubmit={this.form.submit} name="signup" noValidate>
          <input type="text" name="firstName" value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <input type="text" name="lastName" value={this.state.lastName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
       

            <div class="s72-buttons">
                <button type="submit"</button>
            </div>
        </form>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error lives in your `onSubmit` at your `<form/>` you have it like this

```
this.form.submit
```

but `this.form` does not exists, there for the default behavior takes place

```js
export default class Signup extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {                
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',        
        };
    
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);

    }

    
    submit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();          
        const regexp = /^\S*$/; 
        const { firstName,lastName }= this.state; 
       
       if (!regexp.test(firstName) || !regexp.test(lastName)) {
         // cancel process, whitespace found;

         return;
       }

        return this.app.register({
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: this.state.lastName,
        }).then(account => success())
        .catch(e => {
            this.setState({ error: `signup_form_error_${e}` });
          })    
    }
    
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value.trim();
        })
    }

    render(props, state) {


        return <form onSubmit={this.submit} name="signup">
          <input pattern="/^\S*$/" type="text" name="firstName" value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <input pattern="/^\S*$/" type="text" name="lastName" value={this.state.lastName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
       

            <div class="s72-buttons">
                <button type="submit">submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>;
    }
}
```

Comment: take a look, I found the problem

Comment: It allows to add special characters haha. I tried to add something like [$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-] but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

**For those using react hook form controller**

You can modify the `onChange` handler like below, to prevent user from typing spaces at all.

```
<Controller
  name='username'
  control={control}
  rules={{ required: true }}
  render={({ field: { value, onChange, onBlur } }) => (
    <TextField
      autoComplete='new-password'
      label='Username'
      value={value}
      onBlur={onBlur}
      onChange={(e) => {
        onChange(e.target.value.trim());
      }}
      error={Boolean(errors.username)}
      inputProps={{ tabIndex: 1, style: { textTransform: "lowercase" } }}
    />
  )}
/>
```

Or alternatively, you can do it after `onBlur` (Below code is to remove consecutive spaces)

```
const removeExtraSpace = (s: string) => s.trim().split(/ +/).join(" ");

<Controller
  name='fullName'
  control={control}
  rules={{ required: true }}
  render={({ field: { value, onChange, onBlur } }) => (
    <TextField
      label='Full Name'
      value={value}
      onBlur={() => {
        onBlur();
        onChange(removeExtraSpace(value));
      }}
      onChange={onChange}
      error={Boolean(errors.fullName)}
      inputProps={{ tabIndex: 2 }}
    />
  )}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

react hook form:

```
<input
    {...register('newPassword')}
     onChange={(evt) =>
         setValue(
             'newPassword',
              evt.currentTarget.value.replace(/ /g, '')
          )
        }
     name='newPassword'
     type='text'
/>
```

only react:

```
<input
    onChange={(evt) => evt.currentTarget.value.replace(/ /g, '')}
    name='newPassword'
    type='text'
/>
```

Comment: Your _pure react_ snippet doesn't work; `onChange={(evt) => evt.currentTarget.value.replace(/ /g, '')}` doesn't have any effect.